# Lua table in C++ dll

Tags: c++, lua

My Lua table is looking like this:

```
qt={
    bid_number=20;
    ask_number=20;
    bid=table of 20 elements;
    ask=table of 20 elemens;
}
```

So `#qt=0`,
I want to send this table to C++ dll and work with its fields.
How can I do it?
For now I can work in C++ dll only with such tables as `tbl={a,b,c}`. I do it like this:

```
static int forLua_SumArray (lua_State* L) {    // Get the length of the table (same as # operator in Lua)
    int n = luaL_len(L, 1);
    double sum = 0.0;

    // For each index from 1 to n, get the table value as a number and add to sum
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      lua_rawgeti(L, 1, i);
      sum += lua_tonumber(L, -1);
      lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_pushnumber(L, sum);
    return 1; 
}
```

Help me please to start working with more complex tables.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_next

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used sol2 https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2 to make complexities in Lua/C++ interfaces much more straightforward.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Convert the Lua value at the given acceptable index to a C string. The Lua value must be a string or a number, otherwise, the function returns null.

```
const char *lua_tolstring (lua_State *L, int index, size_t *len);
```

then `lua_tostring` also changes the actual value in the stack to a string.
`luaL_checkstring` calls `lua_tolstring`.